# Hyperlink comes below the font-awesome Icon. How to place it inline?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Guys I am stuck in making a top info bar where I can put all the necessary details like phone number, mail id and some social icons, and I am using Bootstrap 4.1.3 and Font-awesome 5.5 but whenever I try to put a hyperlink after the icon it comes down to the next line. How to properly align it in one line. I have tried a lots of methods but got no results so far.

Please check the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Anything</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="top-info d-sm-none d-md-block">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><span><a href="#">Login</a></span></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><span><a href="#">Login</a></span></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><span><a href="#">Login</a></span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><span><a href="#">Login</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Which icon is being misplaced?

Comment: Your code is too long and there are so many FontAwesome icons. Which one is fault? Just show the relevant code, it saves us the time to search for the error(s).

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I need the <li> items should come in one row. :(

Comment: @Sagar I suggest you to post a snippet here

Comment: @VipulSharma In Snippet it comes as I wanted but in reality it is not coming.

Comment: That sounds weird. Then there should be a problem in the code at your local machine.

Comment: Thanks @VipulSharma, This problem is solved now. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some things in your code, i added the class `col-md-8` in the faulty div and so the code is this one `<div class="col-md-8">`. You can also check the result here https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/xyOoBB?editors=1000. My guess is that because originally you used `col-md-4` it would be a bit buggy. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Radu but I need that all the <li> items should come in one row like in one line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, in the question you wanted to align the hyperlink with the icon and now you say you want all of them in one line?

Comment: If you want all of the 4 links in one line try this: https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/xyOoBB?editors=1000

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in giving title.

Comment: Try the link in my last comment, i changed the div class to `col-md-12` and they all show inline

Comment: Thanks Radu It worked like charm. You are a genius. :-)

Comment: No problem, you get the hand of it after some time just remember that sometimes the solution is easier than you think :D

Answer (score 0):

Include i tag inside span tag like this

`<span> <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"><a href="#">Login</a></i></span>`
https://jsfiddle.net/isubhamb/jztosgbd/13/